# show n lines after a grep search

Tags: shell, awk, grep, find

I am trying to display the 5 lines after searching though a list of files for a pattern in the files content. I am running this on a MacOSX shell.

I tried doing this

```
grep -A5 'pattern' *.*
```

Here I get the following output

```
filename
line1
filename
line2
filename
line3
filename
line4
filename
line5
```

I however just want the lines as the output and not the file names. My ideal output would be 
filename

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I also tried the following but they didn't work.

```
grep -l 'pattern' *.* | head -5
head -5 < grep -l 'pattern' *.*
```

Any idea on how to do this on the shell?

Comment: Can you show your input file?

Comment: This seems like that is actually the contents of the file.

Comment: @pogo: Question will be clear only if we know what is your input data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `grep` to omit filenames from its output when it has multiple input files, then you should use the `-h` option (or you can use `--no-filename` instead if your grep happens to be the GNU flavor).

Also, the `-A5` option gives (up to) 5 lines of context around each match.  If that's what you want then well and good, but it looks like perhaps you instead want to limit `grep` to 5 matches.  That would be `-m5` for max 5 per file, or pipe it into `head -5` if you want only 5 overall.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
cat *.* | grep -A 5 'pattern'
```

Yet please clarify if you want to show only (1) total 5 lines, (2) 5 lines per file, or (3) 5 lines after each pattern match.  My answer fits the last one, i.e. 5 lines after each pattern match.